# time out error happened while using mantis

Tags: time, out, mantis

While clicking manage user link in mantis i got this error

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\projName\core\session_api.php on line 121
```

Call Stack is

```
# Time Memory Function Location 
1 0.0037 486896 {main}( ) ..\manage_user_page.php:0 
2 0.0056 552952 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\projName\core.php' ) ..\manage_user_page.php:26 
3 0.1327 3581232 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\projName\core\session_api.php' ) ..\core.php:185 
4 0.1363 3695936 session_init( ) ..\session_api.php:317 
5 0.1365 3696216 MantisPHPSession->__construct( ) ..\session_api.php:186
```

how do i solve it

Answer (score 1):

You can try to increase [max-execution-time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in your php.ini file.

That being said, it seems strange to get a timeout on this page - how many users do you have in your system ?